# How can I Set Full Screen Background Image to Scaffold Container

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I would like to Set Full-Screen Background Image to Scaffold Container, but don't know how? Here is my code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _deviceHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    _deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
        title: Text(this.widget._receiverName),
      ),
      body: ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthProvider>.value(
        value: AuthProvider.instance,
        child: _conversationPageUI(),
      )
    );
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

wrap your scaffold with container and set its decoration

```
 Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(image: DecorationImage(image: AssetImage("... your image"))),
      child: Scaffold(),
    );
```

dont forgot to set scaffold background to Colors.transparent